# What determines the icon for entries in the New context menu?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, icons, context-menu

I'm not entirely sure how this works. So I can add items to the "new" context menu (that appears when right clicking or pressing the menu button) through the registry editor. For example, if I want to create a new .cpp file entry, I can import a .reg file that looks like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.cpp]
@="cpp"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.cpp\ShellNew]
"NullFile"=""
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cpp]
@="C++ File"
```

So I can set the extension and the description that appears for it using this method. However, I'm not sure how the icon that appears next to my description is decided. This is what I mean:

[image]

I'm not sure if Windows chooses this picture automatically based upon whatever program I have set as the default for that extension or if it can be set manually in the registry somehow.

**Can this icon be set manually?**

Comment: This video is always worth a watch for such hackery - https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-176-CMD-and-PowerShell-Context-Menus

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By default, Explorer will use the icon set by the file type, but this can be overriden by placing an `IconPath` value in the `ShellNew` key. I figured this out by using [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to watch for Registry activity from `explorer.exe`.

It looks like Windows's existing entries use the `REG_EXPAND_SZ` data type, but `REG_SZ` works equally well and is much easier to include in a REG file. The format is the full path to the file containing the icon, then a comma, then the number of the icon resource within the file. In this screenshot, I used `%ProgramFiles%\Windows Mail\wab.exe,10`:

[image: ShellNew entries]

As you can see, this doesn't affect the file's icon outside of the New list:

[image: the file's icon is different from the New icon]

To include that change in your REG file, add this line right under the `"NullFile"=""` one:

```
"IconPath"="%ProgramFiles%\\Windows Mail\\wab.exe,10"
```

You will need to restart Explorer for the change to take effect.

Comment: I'm surprised that `REG_SZ` works with environment variables. Possibly Explorer expands it again.

Comment: @Bob Except for character set conversion for the A functions, [the value type does not change the behavior](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090205-00/?p=19243) of `RegQueryValueEx`. The .NET Framework [will do the expansion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `REG_EXPAND_SZ` values by default, but the underlying Windows API does not.

Answer (score 3):

#### Can this icon be set manually?

Yes, using [File Types Manager](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) from [NirSoft](https://www.nirsoft.net/):

**About File Types Manager**

> FileTypesMan is an alternative to the 'File Types' tab in the 'Folder
>   Options' of Windows. It displays the list of all file extensions and
>   types registered on your computer. For each file type, the following
>   information is displayed: Type Name, Description, MIME Type, Perceived
>   Type, Flags, Browser Flags, and more. FileTypesMan also allows you to
>   easily edit the properties and flags of each file type, as well as it
>   allows you to add, edit, and remove actions in a file type.
>
> System Requirements
>
> This utility works on any version of Windows from Windows 98 to
>   Windows 10. For using this utility under Windows 98/ME, you must
>   download the non-Unicode version. For using this utility under x64
>   system, you should download the x64 version.

Source [FileTypesMan - Alternative to 'File Types' manager of Windows](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html)

---

**Detailed Instructions**

> The first thing you’ll need to do is download a copy of File Types
>   Manager. It works in pretty much any version of Windows, but do pay
>   attention to whether you need the 32- or 64-bit version. If you’re not
>   sure, here’s how to figure out whether you’re running a 32-bit or
>   64-bit version of Windows.
>
> When the download finishes, unzip the folder. It’s a portable app, so
>   you won’t need to install it—just double-click “FileTypesMan.exe” to
>   get started.
>
> [image: fte_1]
>
> Click the “Default Icon” column header to sort the list by the Default
>   Icon. Note that for our screenshot, we hid several columns to make
>   things easier to see. You may find the “Default Icon” column further
>   to the right. This groups together all file extensions that already
>   have the same icon. This is convenient if you want to change several
>   related file types that use the same icon. If you only intend to
>   change one file type, feel free to sort by the extension or type name
>   instead.
>
> [image: fte_2]
>
> To save some scrolling, we’ll use the find function to get to the file
>   type we’re after. Click the “Find” button on the toolbar (or press
>   Ctrl+F). In the “Find” window, type in the extension for the file type
>   you want to change and then click the “Find Next” button repeatedly
>   until the you arrive at the extension you’re after. You can then click
>   “Cancel” to close the “Find” window.
>
> [image: fte_3]
>
> Right click extension whose icon you want to change and then select
>   “Edit Selected File Type.”
>
> [image: fte_4]
>
> In the “Edit File Type” window, click the “…” button to the right of
>   the Default Icon text field.
>
> [image: fte_5]
>
> The “Change Icon” window shows some basic icons, but click the
>   “Browse” button to find your own icon files. File Types Manager allows
>   you to select EXE, DLL, or ICO files.
>
> [image: fte_6]
>
> After you’ve browsed for and selected the icon file you want, the
>   available icons will show up in the list. Select the icon you want
>   from the list and then click “OK.” In this example, we’re using icon
>   files that we downloaded from IconArchive, so there’s only one icon
>   shown. If you’re using a EXE or DLL file, you might see many more
>   icons than with an ICO file.
>
> [image: fte_7]
>
> If you need to change the icon for more than one file type, you just
>   need to repeat those steps. And when you’re done, you can close File
>   Type Manager and open up a File Explorer window to check out your
>   changes. In our example, we’ve changed the icons for GIF and PNG file
>   types—two types of picture files we use a lot—to make them a bit
>   easier to distinguish. Before, all picture files were using the same
>   icon—the default icon of our image viewer app.
>
> [image: fte_8]

Source [How to Change the Icon for a Certain File Type in Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12383/change-a-file-types-icon-in-windows-7/)

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [NirSoft](https://www.nirsoft.net/) in any way, I am just an end user of their software.

Comment: Note that this changes the icon of the file type system-wide. This is a useful program though.

Answer (score 0):

For the record:
a blank line must be added after the first line ("Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00") of a *.reg file, or it will throw an error when executed. See:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/310516/how-to-add-modify-or-delete-registry-subkeys-and-values-by-using-a-reg#syntax for syntax details.

BTW, this is not really an answer to the question, but being new here I'm not allowed to comment.
But moderators @robinCTS and @bertieb suggest it can also be submitted as an answer, so here I go.
Maybe one of these moderators can move it to the comment zone of the question (and at the same time edit out this par.)? 
Thx!