# Adding Python, and C++ file to New Item

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

This [Question](https://superuser.com/questions/34704/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-the-new-context-menu) is useful, I do not down play that, it has helped me add HTML, and Fortran 90 file types to my Context menu. However, it is not working for python and c++ I have tried this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py]
"backup_val"="Python.File"
"PerceivedType"="text"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py\OpenWithProgids]
"VisualStudio.py.f8b4906c"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py\ShellNew]
"NullFile"=""
"FileName"="C:\\Windows\\ShellNew\\Template.py"
```

As well as physically editing the registry editor. Any clues to why this I can't add Python files to my context menu. I don't know what you might need so I am giving you my SS(that's a joke just that quarantine has me on my laptop and I wanna be efficient), and other info, by that I mean my windows version, and OS name. My information is :

- Version  10.0.18363 Build 18363
- OS Name  Microsoft Windows 10 Home

If you need anything else please feel free to comment, this is my first post, and I have followed the guidelines in that previous question and it has not worked out. I am oblivious to where the error may lie. Thank you in advance.

I have kept trying, and this does not work either for the python file item to appear on my new item context.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py]
@="Python"
"Content Type"="text/x-python"
"Python"="Python"
"PerceivedType"="text"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py\ShellNew]
"NullFile"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python]
@="Python Script"
```

While I was typing this edit I tried a different route and got this but it still does not work.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py]
"backup_val"="Python.File"
"PerceivedType"="text"
@=""
"Content Type"="application/pycharm"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py\OpenWithProgids]
"VisualStudio.py.f8b4906c"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py\ShellNew]
"ItemType"="C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm Community Edition with Anaconda plugin 2019.2.1\\bin\\pycharm64.exe"
```

- I have tried searching for executable to produce .py files like in the case of notepad, and it is a route I am looking at. That has not worked.
- I have tried editing my system variables to include `"C:\Windows\ShellNew"`, I have created template .cpp, and .py files, and I even tried using an `python.exe` to see if I can create a file from the context menu.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.cpp]
@="cpp"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.cpp\ShellNew]
"NullFile"=""
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cpp]
@="C++ File"
```

This code from this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1337520/what-determines-the-icon-for-entries-in-the-new-context-menu) helped solve my CPP file dilemma, I am going to try it from Python. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: I tried an exe route like the rtf, but it does not work, and the file template I tried that, and null file  = 1, I am runnning out of ideas for what to try, but I am glad for you taking your time and answer my question\

Comment: Why is this question asking us to submit commentary?  What exactly is your question?