# Why isn't my custom context menu entry showing an icon?

Tags: windows-registry, windows-11, icons, context-menu

On Windows 11, I have added a custom context menu item for .stl files by adding a new key in `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.stl` in the registry that links to the .exe I want to use: `"C:\Program Files\OrcaSlicer\orca-slicer.exe" "%1"`.

The command itself works fine, but I would like to add the icon of the program in the context menu. However, this does not seem to work. Multiple guide I found online say that you should add a 'Icon' String with a link to the icon, but this never works. I have tried linking to the .exe of the program itself, I have tried extracting the .ico files and linking to the 32x32 and 256x256 .ico files, I have tried linking to an .ico on a different drive, nothing works.

```
Icon    REG_SZ    "C:\Program Files\OrcaSlicer\orca-slicer.exe"
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What determines the icon for entries in the New context menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/1337520/what-determines-the-icon-for-entries-in-the-new-context-menu)

Comment: That is related to the icon for the entire filetype, I only want to edit the new context menu entry that I made to open it with the orca slicer program.